# XML Parse Error

Tags: php, jquery, xml

I have this [jquery code](http://jsfiddle.net/4h908ube/1/) that takes an xml variable parse it and display it in a html file, and it works as supposed.
The problem is once I try to take the xml variable from a php script and give this varibale as an input of the above jquery script I get an error message in my web browser.

My script:

```
<?php
require('MyClass.php');
$Myparam = "0123641";
$built_request=new MyClass($Myparam);
$xml=$built_request->getResponse();// works fine and returns an xml variable represented as below
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<BODY>
<p id="someElement"></p>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var xml ="<?php echo $xml; ?>";
var d1 = $(xml).find('data[name="name2"]').attr('status');
$( "#someElement" ).append( d1 );
});
</script>
</BODY>
</html>
```

This is the obtained error in the web browser despite when I give this same xml variable direct in the javascript, the script works.

```
    XML Parse Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
    var xml ="<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
--------------^
```

Trying to investigate this problem I printed my obtained variable and the printed value is as following:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <data request-id="31236">
    <data name="name1" code="0" code2="003404502" code3="">
      <data name="name2" code1="34297502" time="2014-09-01" id="14c259b-bsdfgds8b5" leitcode="" code2="692748" order="false" piece-code="00363932" piece-status="0" identifier-type="2" pan-recipient-name="" street-name="" house-number="" city-name="" status="status x" error-status="0" code_name="code name" />
      </data>
    </data>
```

Comment: The problems seems to be the new lines in your string(I'm guessing it)... if so you need to escape it... not sure how to do it in PHP... you will have to change the line `var xml ="<?php echo $xml; ?>";`

Comment: actually there is no new lines in my xml variable could please take a look to my edited question

Answer (score 0):

Your inline JavaScript is being rendered into a form similar to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var xml ="<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                 <data request-id="ID">
                 ... ";

    var d1 = $(xml).find('data[name="name2"]').attr('status');
    $( "#someElement" ).append( d1 );

});
```

Note the `xml` line: it is outputting double quotes multiple times within the string itself. The following should resolve this:

```
var xml = "<?= str_replace('"', '\"', $xml); ?>";
```

Comment: @Amani Can you view the source and share it somewhere, so I can see what the current output is? Thanks.

Comment: `<parsererror>XML Parse Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
Adresse: http://swebsite/test.php
Zeile Nr. 10, Spalte 11:<sourcetext>var xml ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <data request-id="123654"><data name="name1" code="0" code2="05782" zip-code=""><data name="name2" time="2014-09-02 " id="14c3d1-48385" leitcode="" status="status x" error-status="0" name="name" /></data></data>';
----------^</sourcetext></parsererror>`

Comment: @Amani Is that error coming from PHP or from JavaScript? That error makes it look like PHP is trying to parse the XML, not JavaScript.

Comment: it is a php file `test.php` see the content of my file in question

Comment: the returned value of the function above `getResponse()` (the xml variable) is this `$response = file_get_contents($myUrl, false, $Request);`

Comment: @Amani PHP shouldn't be parsing the XML when it's been output, that's all. Just on the off-chance, try replacing `<script>` with `<script type='text/javascript'>`; it might be that your PHP parser is confused.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you should change the code :

```
var xml ="<?php echo $xml; ?>";
```

to

```
var xml ='<?php echo $xml; ?>';
```

***EDITED:***

I make a simple test:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
     var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <data request-id="31236"><data       name="name1" code="0" code2="003404502" code3=""> <data name="name2" code1="34297502" time="2014-09-01" id="14c259b-bsdfgds8b5" leitcode="" code2="692748" order="false" piece-code="00363932" piece-status="0" identifier-type="2" pan-recipient-name="" street-name="" house-number="" city-name="" status="status x" error-status="0" code_name="code name" /></data></data>'
     var d1 = $(xml).find('data[name="name2"]').attr('status');
     console.log(d1);
</script>
```

it's work fine

output:

```
   status x
```

Answer (score 0):

`var xml ='<?php echo $xml; ?>';`

Please use the above code to get the proper result. As you have the double quotes in your xml document it didnt work if you place double quotes when you are getting the value in javacsript.